# Custom Image creation in IBM Cloud failing from COS

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

I am working on creating custom image in IBM Cloud using python. I have a very simple straight code for just creating the image and it fails.
As per me I am passing the relevant correct details for all the parameters.

Still I get an Error which is not much descriptive :

```
ERROR:root:Please check whether the resource you are requesting exists.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deepali.mittal/GITHUB/dcoa/python/build/dmittal/virtual-env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py", line 246, in send
    response.status_code, http_response=response)
ibm_cloud_sdk_core.api_exception.ApiException: Error: Please check whether the resource you are requesting exists., Code: 400

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is not related to the resource missing in COS. As if it is not able to find the image in COS it gives a different error.

Code :

```
from ibm_vpc import VpcV1 as vpc_client
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core import ApiException
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
from boto3 import client as boto3_client
import logging

#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

SOURCE_OBJECT_PATH = 'cos://us-south/de-images-dmittal/abc.qcow2'
RESOURCE_GROUP_ID = '1234'
OPERATING_SYSTEM = 'ubuntu-16-amd64'


def create_ssm_client():
    ssm_client = boto3_client("ssm", region_name="us-west-2")
    return ssm_client


def retrieve_ibm_config(ssm_client):
    params = ["/ibm/service-key"]
    response = ssm_client.get_parameters(Names=params, WithDecryption=True)
    try:
        api_key = response["Parameters"][0]["Value"]
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        raise RuntimeError(
            f"Required SSM parameters not retrieved. "
            f'Required parameters are: {params}.'
        )
    return api_key


def create_authenticator(api_key):
    authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(api_key)
    return authenticator


def create_ibm_client(authenticator):
    ibm_client = vpc_client('2021-05-28', authenticator=authenticator)
    return ibm_client


def create_image_prototype():
    image_file_prototype_model = {'href': SOURCE_OBJECT_PATH}
    operating_system_identity_model = {'name': OPERATING_SYSTEM}
    resource_group_identity_model = {'id': RESOURCE_GROUP_ID}
    image_prototype_model = {
        'name': 'my-image',
        #'resource_group': resource_group_identity_model,
        'file': image_file_prototype_model,
        'operating_system': operating_system_identity_model
    }

    image_prototype = image_prototype_model
    return image_prototype


def create_image():
    ssm_client = create_ssm_client()
    api_key = retrieve_ibm_config(ssm_client)
    authenticator = create_authenticator(api_key)
    ibm_client = create_ibm_client(authenticator)
    image_prototype = create_image_prototype()
    try:
        #images = ibm_client.list_images()
        #print(vpc)
        #ibm_client.set_service_url('https://us-south.iaas.cloud.ibm.com/v1')
        response = ibm_client.create_image(image_prototype)
        print(response)
    except ApiException as e:
        print("Failed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_image()
```

Comment: list_images() works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with IAM Permission. After fixing it worked, the error shown was not relevant so it took time to figure out